# why does replace ' ' to ' ' not replaces?

Tags: python, replace

```
test=[]
words_reverse=[]
bad_char=[' ','“','”']
words=[]
def is_words(alist):
    words=['Madam','A tack for tooth','hi im john']
    test.append(words[0][::-1].lower())
    test.append(words[1][::-1].lower())
    test.append(words[2][::-1].lower())
    print(test)
    for q in test:
        for w in q:
            if(w in bad_char):
                q.replace(w,'')
is_words(words)
print(test)
```

for the area where it states for q in test: ...

I do not under why the spacing `' '` is not being replace by the empty string `''` in test and still printing the spacing.

Comment: `replace()` doesn't work in place, so you just lose the change.

Comment: what do you mean by work in place?

Comment: `replace()` returns the changed string, it doesn't change `q`.

Comment: @Pandoriecho work in place means it change the value of q, no replace does not, it just return a new value that is replaced